# How do I turn my verbal argument into something formal in [Real Analysis]? (proving every compact set is bounded)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

So one of the exercises I am doing is to prove (or disprove) that 'Every compact set on a metric space is bounded'. Verbally, I can 'prove' this by simply stating: "If the every compact set on a metric space is not bounded, then there exists an infinite number of open covers, and if something is compact, there are only a finite number of open covers. This is a contradiction, and thus every compact set on a metric space is bounded."

Two questions: is this argument right? And if so, how to I learn how to represent this formally?

Comment: What do you mean by a "finite number of open covers"? There are still an infinite number of open covers for a compact set... except that all of them have a finite subcover

Comment: Your argument doesn't really work. Compactness says "Every open cover has a finite subcover." The negation of this statement is "there exists an open cover which has *no* finite subcover." So, if you want to prove the desired statement by contrapositive, you must start with an unbounded set and exhibit an open cover with no finite subcover.

Comment: To attempt to answer the second part of the question - if the statements you make in the proof were correct, and the exercise occurs in a context in which they had been proved earlier, then I would say your proof is sufficiently formal as it is.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with [J. Loreaux's commrent above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877903/how-do-i-turn-my-verbal-argument-into-something-formal-in-real-analysis-prov/877932#comment1811276_877903) (“Your argument doesn't really work”), and I'd go farther: to me, your argument makes no sense whatever, for several reasons:

1. You say “If the every compact set on a metric space is not bounded, then …”.  This is at least confusingly stated.  You want to prove that every compact set is bounded. You seem to be trying to do a proof by contradiction.  To do this, you need to assume the negation of the statement “Every compact set is bounded”.  The negation of this statement is “there exists an unbounded compact set”.  But instead you seem to be assuming that *every* compact set is unbounded.  This is a much stronger assumption, and proving a contradiction from it will not allow you to conclude that every compact set is bounded; it will only allow you to conclude that *some* compact set is bounded, which is useless. (There are much simpler arguments to prove that.)

   Note that the statements “every cat is not black” and “not every cat is black” are quite different.  The first is false, but the second is true.
2. Your conclusion from the puzzling assumption is that “there exists an infinite number of open covers,” which is puzzling because an open cover has to cover *something* and you didn't say what was being covered.  In the context of a particular set $S$ which might or might not be compact, the reader will assume from context that the phrase “open cover” means “open cover of $S$”.  But there is no such context here because the preceding phrase is talking about *every* compact set.
3. “if something is compact, there are only a finite number of open covers” is strange and, at least as you stated it, false.   There are any number of examples of compact sets which have an infinite family of open covers.

I could go on, but I think this is enough.  I think many people reading your argument, including the grader in your class, will conclude that you have no idea what a compact set is.  Perhaps they would be wrong, but if so you have to do better or that is what they are likely to think.

---

An open cover $C$ of some set $S$ is a family of open sets whose union contains $S$.

A set $S$ is compact if *every* open cover of $S$ has a finite subcover.  That means that if you have a family $C$ of open sets whose union contains $S$, you can always find a finite subset $C'\subset C$ whose union also contains $S$.

Here we want to show that if $S$ is a compact subset of a metric space, then $S$ is bounded.  Take an arbitrary compact set $S$.  If we can show that $S$ is bounded, we are done.  Find a cover $C$ of $S$ whose members are open balls of radius 1. (You need to fill in the details to show that such a cover $C$ of $S$ exists.)  Let $C'$ be finite subcover of this set $C$ of open balls which still covers $S$; we can find $C'$ because $S$ is compact.  We now have a covering of $S$ with a finite set of open balls of radius 1.  But we can then use the triangle inequality to show that $S$ has bounded diameter. (You need to fill in some details here too.)

(I see that [the argument of DanZimm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/877926/25554) elsewhere in this thread is somewhat simpler.)

Comment: Naive Question from a layperson: but if every open cover has a finite subcover, doesn't that mean that there is an excess of open sets that is not really essential in providing the open cover??  Doesn't this mean I could shed a few open sets without compromising the original property of being an open cover?

Comment: @quantumdot Yes, compact sets are special in exactly this way. The example to think of is the open interval interval $I^\circ=(0,1)$ (not compact) and the closed interval $I=[0,1]$ (compact). $I^\circ$ can be covered by the family $\left(\frac1{n+2}, \frac 1n\right)$ for $n\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, and there is no finite subcover of this family that still covers $I^\circ$. But this family does *not* cover $I$, and to cover $I$ you have to add at least one more open set to the family, and no matter how you do it, the extra sets plus a finite subfamily of the original family will cover $[0,1]$.

Comment: that explanation is really helpful. thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is essentially correct but pay attention to the essentially.

I would phrase it in words like so:

> If not every compact set on a metric space is bounded then there exists at least one compact set on a metric space that is not bounded. Since it's unbounded we can construct an infinite open covering which doesn't have a finite subcover thus this unbounded compact set cannot actually exist.

Note the few differences I have

- First I say *there exists at least one compact set on a metric space that is not bounded*. This is needed because we need some sort of compact set to work with - otherwise we're really not being precise with what we're saying since *every compact set on a metric space is not bounded* could be misleading (one could think you're stating every compact set on a metric space is unbounded, which is subtly different).
- Next I say *Since it's unbounded we can construct an infinite open covering which doesn't have a finite subcover*. This is the very important part and why I said "pay attention to the essentially". The root of the contradiction is that there does exist an open cover without a finite subcover, which is exactly what I stated here.

---

Now I encourage you to make things mathy, but below is what I came up with.

> Claim: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, then every compact subset of $X$ is bounded. Proof: Assume $\exists A \subset X$ compact and unbounded. Put $\mathcal{V} = \{ B_0(n) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ then $\mathcal{V}$ is an open covering of $A$ but there doesn't exist a finite subcover, since if there was one then $A$ would become bounded. Note that $B_0(n)$ is the ball centered at $0$ of radius $n$.

---

I want to add the following comment: When I said your argument is essentially correct I meant that it appears you had the essence of the proof in mind, not that you could use this argument exactly how it is for a precise, formal or really even informal proof. I apologize for being misleading - from my perspective it seems like you have an idea on what's going on but are unfamiliar with wording things in a precise manner (in some sense this is exactly what math is), but I would still argue that having this base intuition is also important. To put it concisely, sorry for being misleading, you're argument is *not* valid, but it appears (at least to me) that you have the proper intuition.

Comment: I think you mean "If not every compact set on a metric space is bounded...".

Comment: Curious about the downvoter, comments?

Comment: @MattPressland my apologies you're right I was being misleading, sometimes I try to relate to what the OP is saying too much :P

Comment: @user46257 glad to help, lemme know if you have any questions!